# Loading external library in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, react-redux

I am using React and Redux. Inside my Reducer I am using `lodash` library.

`debugger;`  command stops the execution

If I import `lodash` library

`import _ from "../../node_modules/lodash";`

or

`import _ from "lodash";`

[image]

It fails. It cannot import the library. There is no loading error when I run my React application. I was wondering how do you load an external library(i.e `lodash`) in Google Chrome console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dynamic import syntax instead, and you'll get back a Promise with what you want. For example, on this page:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57032914/loading-external-library-in-chrome-console
```

using

```
import('../../foo')
```

results in

[image]

Assuming that on your own site, the link is proper, all you need to do is call `.then` on the Promise:

```
import("../../node_modules/lodash")
  .then((_) => {
    // do stuff with _
  });
```

(of course, this requires that `node_modules` be a subfolder of the grandparent directory of the current page)

Comment: Thanks. I tried  `import("../../node_modules/lodash").then((_)=>{  _.mapKeys([{"id": 1, "val": 'a'}, {"id": 2, "val": 'b'}],"id")}) ` it only returns a promise. I was wondering how to get the `_.mapkeys()` return value?

Comment: It's asynchronous - you have to work with the Promise itself, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call . A value that's retrieved asynchronously can't be used synchronously.

Comment: Put everything in the `.then` so that it runs after the module has been retrieved.

Comment: Sorry, not clear. I have added all code inside `then()`. Please check my previous code.

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the return value of `mapKeys`. Eg if you wanted to log it: https://gist.github.com/CertainPerformance/7dc57f836fbc395bcfe9661cbb4314e6

Comment: Thanks for the code. I have added console.log. but it did not work(only returns promise). `import("../../node_modules/lodash").then( 
(_)=>{ console.log (_.mapKeys([{"id": 1, "val": 'a'}, {"id": 2, "val": 'b'}],"id")) })`

Comment: What do you mean, "only returns promise"? `import` *always* returns a Promise, that's what it's supposed to do, right? The log statement should work if the Lodash you're using is being exported properly - eg, to use `_.mapKeys`, you need the module to have `export function mapKeys(...` or something of the sort as part of its code.

Answer (score 1):

The least complicated way I found is this:

- Copy the html below into a file and save it as .html file (example - testLodash.html). It can work for any other library, just get the cdn for the library into the script tag.
- Open the file in the browser (in my case Chrome) - It opens a blank page.
- Open browser console and start using it. For example `_.groupBy([6.1, 4.2, 6.3], Math.floor)` . console logs `{4: Array(1), 6: Array(2)}`

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset=utf-8 />

   </head>

   <body>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4/lodash.min.js"></script>

   </body>
</html>
```